# Why does Charmap only throw an error in dictionary form but not JSON form?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, encoding

```
response = requests.request("GET", requestUrl, headers=headers, data=payload)
data = response.json()
dataJSON = json.dumps(data)
print (dataJSON) #Prints perfectly fine
#dataDict = json.loads(dataJSON)
#print(dataDict) #throws charmap Exception that is below
```

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 107450-107451: character maps to <undefined>
```

I Have tried UTF-8 encoding and that does nothing to resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: `json.dumps` automatically escapes non-ASCII characters to their `\uxxxx` equivalents, so the JSON string is printable in any locale that works with ASCII.  In the dictionary, such characters are not escaped and so attempts to print them will fail if the locale encoding cannot encode any non-ASCII characters that might be present.  Try running your script like this: `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 python myscript.py` (assuming that you are running it from the command prompt).

Comment: @snakecharmerb I am not using the command prompt. But the final form I need my data does not have this issue either. So, theoretically, if I edit all my data while in the dictionary form and never print it. I can get away without a charmap errors? Or will these errors follow me while I manipulate said dictionary? (if your curious my final file format is CSV) but thank you for clearing all this up for me!

Comment: The error will happen whether you are writing to a file or to the console.  However for file IO you can specify an encoding, for example `open('myfile.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8', ...)`.  UTF-8 can encode any character so it's a good choice.  UTF-8-SIG is a variant of UTF-8 used by Excel, so that is another possible candidate.